# Can an algebraic space fail to have a universal map to a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-spaces, schemes, examples

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an algebraic space. Can it happen that there does not exist a map $\mathcal{X} \to X$ with $X$ a scheme that is initial for maps from $\mathcal{X}$ to schemes? Are there reasonable conditions (e.g. finite type) that we can put on $\mathcal{X}$ so that there does exist such a universal map to a scheme?

Comment: Isn;t there always a map to $\mathrm{Spec}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$? This would be an initial object for morphisms to affine schemes.

Comment: One may perhaps formulate a modification (pun intended!) to the question. Given a reduced irreducible algebraic space $\mathcal{X}$ is there a morphism to a scheme $Y$ such that the function field of $Y$ is the same as the function field of $\mathcal{X}$. Is there a theorem of Artin on this question?

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is almost certainly yes, an algebraic space can fail to have a universal map to a scheme (a "schemification"). I don't have a proof, but I think I know the right place to look for one (besides David Rydh's immediate surroundings).

If we can find two maps of schemes which do not have a coequalizer in the category of schemes, but do have a coequalizer in the category of algebraic spaces, then the coequalizer algebraic space will not have a schemification.

Consider Hironaka's example of a non-projective proper variety (see page 15 of Knutson's [Algebraic Spaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059750)). It has an action of ℤ/2 for which there is an algebraic space quotient. But in the category of schemes, there is no *geometric quotient* for this action. The question is whether there is a *categorical quotient* in this case.

Comment: I wondered about that example when reading about algebraic spaces.  Does anyone know the answer to this question?