# Colimit of an etale diagram of schemes

Tags: schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry, limits-and-colimits

It is known that the category of schemes is not cocomplete (e.g. see this question: [Colimits of schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9961/colimits-of-schemes)). However, do diagrams of schemes for which every morphism is etale have colimits? More generally, I'd really like to know if, given a scheme $X$, if the category of etale schemes over $X$ is cocomplete. I should mention that I know very little of algebraic geometry. I'm interested for "categorical reasons".

Comment: The answer to you first question ("do diagrams of schemes for which every morphism is etale have colimits?") is no: there are examples in which you have two étale maps that have no coequalizer in the category of schemes.

You can find one of those in the book "Algebraic spaces" by Knutson (on page 14). The point is that there is a scheme $X$ with an action of $Z/2Z$ that doesn't have a quotient in the category of schemes, so the two maps $X\times Z/2Z \to X$ given by the action and the projection will not have a coequalizer (but they are étale).

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you make this into an answer instead of a comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mattia: You seem to be making the same mistake that many made in response to the question linked in the statement of the question: just because the *quotient* doesn't exist as an algebraic space, it does not follow that there cannot be a categorical co-equalizer in the category of schemes (which may not be a quotient).  Being a quotient is a stronger property.  (Admittedly this is a picky point, since if such a co-equalizer exists it would be useless since it lacks other good properties, but nonetheless it is not evident, strictly speaking, if your suggested example is really an example. 

Comment: @Boyarsky: I think you're right, the fact is that when I read of this counterexample I always thought of "quotient" as of "categorical quotient", and was thus convinced that it was proved that there is no categorical quotient (my bad).

Comment: But does there exist a real counterxample? It'd be nice if these colimits existed, but, I'm guessing they don't...

Comment: It's clear that such a co-equalizer, if it exists, is quite useless, and that the algebraic space quotient is the "right" object, so is there a reason beyond idle curiosity to wonder about these things? (By the way, I don't doubt that it can be fun to wonder about it, at least for a little bit of time, but it does feel sort of irrelevant to actually using the theory.) Basically, is there a reason to care? I feel as if the success of algebraic spaces implies that one never needs to spend time on these kinds of questions

Comment: I care because, if category of etale schemes over $X$ is cocomplete for each scheme $X$, then I can left-Kan extend the identify functor along Yoneda and get a functor $L:Sh(X) \to Et/X$ which is an analogue of the espace-etale of a sheaf over a space (Sh(X) is the etale topos of sheaves). Maybe this can be done by going to algebraic spaces instead?

Comment: @David: (i) I don't believe co-completeness holds, (ii) even if it does, it would surely have poor properties (e.g., behavior for base change on the co-equalizer) so as to rule out working locally on it, (iii) the algebraic space quotient is the "right" object of study.  ((iii) is the reason for (ii).) I don't know what a "left-Kan extension" is, so I can't figure out what makes such an $L$ interesting to have. What's the motivation?  If you can say what you would do with it, perhaps it can be determined whether using algebraic spaces makes the whole issue become moot. 

Comment: @Boyasky: As you might now, if $X$ is a topological space and $F$ is a sheaf, then you can construct the espace-etale of $F$, which is an etale space over $X$. Abstractly, what you do is, write $F$ as a colimit of representables, and then take the colimit of the "same" diagram viewing each representable as an etale space over $X$ (i.e., view an open subset $U$ as a map $U \hookrightarrow X$.). I wanted to do the same to the etale-site of a scheme.

Comment: @David: there are known tricks to reduce many general problems to the representable case, so I don't see how it would be useful even if it could be done. (Algebraic spaces won't help much; the diagonal won't be representable.) Anyway, here is a way it hits a snag without *more* properties: in practice we evaluate on objects outside of the small etale site, so we often need compatibility with general base change akin to that for quotients defining algebraic spaces.  Likewise it is too weak to have a co-equalizer: you need it to be such after any base change (not just flat) on the co-equalizer. 

Comment: +1. Which morphisms between the etale schemes do you want to allow?

Comment: With a fixed base scheme $X$, I'd have to allow any map between etale schemes over $X$ that make a commutative triangle, to do what I want. There's a good chance what I want is simply not reasonable.

Comment: For the record the answer is yes if you replace schemes by algebraic spaces: the wide subcategory of algebraic spaces consisting of étale morphisms admits all small colimits, computed in étale sheaves. Coproducts are obvious, and to compute the coequalizer of a pair of étale maps V → U one can replace V by its image in U × U, then the coequalizer in sheaves of groupoids is discrete and trivially a DM stack, so it is an algebraic space.

Comment: Moreover, the notion of algebraic space is designed to provide an analog of the étalé space construction for étale sheaves: the category of étale algebraic spaces over a scheme (or algebraic space) X is equivalent to the small étale topos of X (in other words, every étale sheaf is representable). In particular, this implies that étale schemes over X do not in general suffice to get an étalé space from which the sheaf can be recovered.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks Marc. I asked this question 8 years ago, so in fact now, I am aware of exactly what you said about algebraic spaces. Nonetheless, thanks for taking the time to respond!