# Pushouts of noetherian rings

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, counterexamples, noetherian

Does the category of noetherian commutative rings have pushouts?

Background: If $X/S$ is an abelian scheme, then the relative Picard functor $\mathrm{Pic}_{X/S}$ is only defined on the category of locally noetherian $S$-schemes (as far as I know). It is a group functor and in some situations it is representable. We then get a group object in the category of locally noetherian $S$-schemes, and I ask myself if it has a multiplication morphism. [Edit: Boyarsky has mentioned in the comments how to deal with this.]

Observe that the tensor product of noetherian commutative rings does not have to be noetherian (isn't this ugly?). Even for fields there is a counterexample: Let $L/K$ be a purely transcendental field extension of infinite transcendence degree. Then $\Omega^1_{L/K}$ is infinite-dimensional, from which you can concluce that the kernel of $L \otimes_K L \to L, a \otimes b \mapsto ab$  is not finitely generated. Thus $L \otimes_K L$ is not noetherian.

Of course, this does not disprove that $L \leftarrow K \rightarrow L$ has a pushout in the category of noetherian commutative rings. How can this be done? The question has a similar spirit as [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9961/colimits-of-schemes).

Comment: (i) The "locally noetherian" restriction is easy to remove via the limit formalism of EGA IV$_3$, sections 8--12. (ii) It is not "ugly" that the noetherian property is generally lost of the formation of fiber products of noetherian schemes; what is ugly/unnatural is to insist on noetherian hypotheses when unnecessary. As Deligne once said, Grothendieck taught us that it is better to have a category with some "bad" objects and good operations. (iii) Faithfully flat descent provides *natural/useful* examples of non-noetherian schemes ($\widehat{A} \otimes_ A \widehat{A}$); you'll get over it. 

Comment: By the way, the Picard functor is locally of finite presentation, and clearly the (locally) noetherian property is preserved under fiber products when at least one of the structure maps is locally of finite type.  So the assertion that your Picard scheme is a group scheme makes perfectly good sense within the category of locally noetherian schemes if you insist on $S$ being locally noetherian and $X$ projective. (What lies deeper is that the Picard functor of an abelian scheme is an algebraic space when dropping projective hypotheses, and its relative identity component is *always* a scheme.)

Comment: If R-->S is universal for maps from a given ring R to noetherian rings, then by using maps into fields you can show that every prime ideal of R is the contraction of a unique prime ideal of S. If you could also show that this bijection is an order isomorphism, then you could conclude that R has no infinite ascending chain of prime ideals, which would rule out the existence of such a universal map in the case you are looking at ($R=L\otimes_KL$).

Comment: @Tom: there are non-noetherian valuation rings of finite Krull dimension (even spectrum homeomorphic to $[0,n]$ with the order topology), so one cannot infer that even a domain is not noetherian merely from topological considerations with Spec. So your second sentence is unclear. 

Comment: @Boyarsky: Maybe one cannot infer that a ring is noetherian from such considerations, but one can sometimes infer that it is non-noetherian.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I don't understand.  The example I gave was a non-noetherian ring whose spectrum reflects that it has no infinite ascending chain of prime ideals.  So it seems to be a counterexample to your suggested method to prove a ring is not noetherian via a topological argument.  What is the general mechanism by which you propose to prove a ring is non-noetherian by a topological method which would not apply to the non-noetherian example which I mentioned? 

Comment: @Boyarsky: If $R$ has an infinite ascending chain of prime ideals, then $R$ has an infinite ascending chain of ideals. If $R$ has an infinite ascending chain of ideals, then $R$ is non-noetherian.

It is true that there are non-noetherian rings which cannot be detected by this method, but $L\otimes_KL$ is not one of them.

Comment: @Tom: OK, sorry for my misunderstanding of what you were saying.  

Comment: No problem. I was being a little terse. By the way, I don't suppose a noetherian ring can have Spec [0,n] if n>1, can it?

Comment: @Tom: nope, it can't.  The reason is that any noetherian local domain with dimension > 1 has infinitely many height-1 primes (since the union of *finitely many* non-maximal primes cannot equal the maximal ideal in any local ring, by one of those lemmas very early in Atiyah-MacDonald, 1.11 or so, and any nonzero non-unit in a noetherian domain lies in some height-1 prime by the Hauptidealsatz). So in fact the spectrum of such a ring must be infinite as a set.  And $[0,n]$ with the order topology corresponds to being a local domain (after killing nilpotents) with Krull dimension $n$. 

Comment: @Boyarsky, I like that Deligne quote.  Do you have a reference?  (Please email it too!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, and let $\ell = k(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ be the fraction field of $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$. Then $\ell \otimes_k \ell$ is the localisation of $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots][y_1,y_2,\ldots]$ at the multiplicative set
$$S = \left\{fg\ \bigg|\ \begin{array}{ll}f \in k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]\setminus\{0\},\\g \in k[y_1,y_2,\ldots] \setminus\{0\}\end{array}\right\}.$$

> **Claim.** The pushout $\ell \coprod_k \ell$ in the category of Noetherian rings does not exist.

*Proof.* If it does, it has natural maps $\iota_i \colon \ell \to \ell \coprod_k \ell$, hence a natural map $\phi \colon \ell \otimes_k \ell \to \ell \coprod_k \ell$. Consider the ideal $I = (x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2,\ldots) \subseteq \ell \otimes_k \ell$. Since $\ell \coprod_k \ell$ is Noetherian, the ideal in $\ell \coprod_k \ell$ generated by $\phi(I)$ is finitely generated. But if $\phi(I) (\ell \otimes_k \ell)$ is generated by $n$ elements, then the same is true for $\psi(I)A$ for any morphism $\psi \colon \ell \otimes_k \ell \to A$ for a Noetherian ring $A$. On the other hand, consider the ring 
\begin{align*}
A &= (\ell \otimes_k \ell)/(x_{n+2}-y_{n+2},x_{n+3}-y_{n+3},\ldots)\\
&\cong k(z_{n+2},\ldots)[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1},y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}][T^{-1}]\\
&\cong k(z_{n+2},\ldots)(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \underset{{k(z_{n+2},\ldots)}}{\otimes} k(z_{n+2},\ldots)(y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}),
\end{align*}
where
$$T = \left\{fg\ \bigg|\ \begin{array}{ll}f \in k(z_{n+2},\ldots)[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]\setminus\{0\},\\g \in k(z_{n+2},\ldots)[y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}] \setminus\{0\}\end{array}\right\}.$$
Then $\mathfrak p = \psi(I)A = (x_1-y_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}-y_{n+1})$ is a prime ideal with $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p) \geq n+1$, since we have a chain of prime ideals
$$0 \subsetneq (x_1-y_1) \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq (x_1-y_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}).$$
But now [Tag 0BBZ (1)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BBZ) (a form of Krull's Hauptidealsatz) shows that $\mathfrak p$ cannot be generated by $n$ elements. $\square$

Comment: I just realised that different arguments are given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323136/82179).

Comment: Oh, I just saw your answer now.

Comment: In the linked question, François Brunault shows that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \sqcup \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ does not exist in the category of Noetherian commutative rings.

Comment: I like your example (and proof) much more, though :)