# Direct limit of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a ring (say finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field). Then, does $\varinjlim \mathrm{Spec} A[t]/(t^m)$ exist (in the category of schemes)?  And if it does, then is it equal to $\mathrm{Spec} A[[t]]$?

Edit based on comment below: The result holds easily when $A=k$ is a field. Then, $\mathrm{Spec} k[t]/(t^n)$ only has one point and hence, for any scheme $X$ such that we have a family of morphisms $\mathrm{Spec} k[t]/(t^n) \to X$, we can assume that $X$ is affine and the result follows from the equivalence of the category $Ring^{op}$ and the category of affine schemes.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9961/colimits-of-schemes in particular Emerton's answer.

Comment: So, according to the link, it does exist and we do have the equality. How do we actually prove it?

Comment: The proof for the case when $A=k$ (a field) is easy, which is in the 3rd paragraph of Emerton's answer. I'm interested in seeing the proof for the present case or even better, the even more general one mentioned by Emerton in the last paragraph (in the EDIT part).

Comment: It's extremely important to say exactly what category this colimit takes place in.  In particular, affine formal schemes are filtered colimits in the category of presheaves (that is, they are ind-affine schemes).  The category of schemes is _not_ cocomplete, so the colimit must be taken with respect to a certain embedding of the category of schemes into some cocomplete (or at least accessible) category.  For instance, this can be the category of locally ringed spaces or any of the categories of sheaves on $Aff$ with the chaotic, Zariski, etale, or fppf topologies.  

Comment: @Harry: We are taking colimits in the category of schemes, and in this case, the colimit exists.  It is not necessary to pass to the cocomplete settings you suggest, and in fact, we would get different answers if we were to do so.

Comment: @Scott: Ah, I see what you're getting at. I though that in general the "categorical colimit" was supposed to agree with the colimit of schemes when it exists. Is that just false? 

Comment: Dear Brian, I am trying to recover the proof of the claim in the EDIT part of that answer; I will report here if successful, and will add a further edit to that answer if not.

Comment: Dear Emerton: Thanks a lot. I'm interested in seeing the proof as well.

Comment: @Harry: When passing to a larger category and take colimit there, if are lucky and the colimit lies in the smaller category then we are good (provided that the smaller category is a full subcategory). Otherwise, we don't get much information out of it.

Comment: @Qph: What I'm saying is more subtle than that.  You should reread what Scott wrote.  What you said is also not true unless the embedding is cocontinuous (or in this case at least accessible).  

Comment: @Scott: Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the colimit in this case is the "categorical" colimit in any of the "good" algebraic toposes (Zariski, etale, or fppf).  The formal completion is the colimit in the chaotic topos (that is to say, the presheaf topos). 

Comment: @Harry: If you have a full faithful embedding, than if the colimit-in-the-big-category of a diagram in the small category is in fact in (the essential image of) the small category, then it is also the colimit in the small category. What you and Qph are both getting at is that there could be a colimit in the small category which is "further away" than the colimit in the big category.

Comment: A colimit of local schemes (and local transition morphisms) exists and is what you guess. This follows from the characterization of morphisms on local schemes. In particular, we get the result also if $A$ is local. [I think that the discussion above does not touch the question ...]

Comment: For noetherian $A$ (as in question!) all maps $A[[t]] \rightarrow A_a[[t]]$ are flat, and in general the only open subscheme of Spec($A[[t]]$) containing Spec($A$) is the entire scheme, so we win via fpqc descent if for all $a, a' \in A$, Spec($A_{aa'}[[t]]) \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(A_a[[t]] \otimes_{A[[t]]} A_{a'}[[t]])$ factors through no proper subscheme of the target that is closed subscheme of an open subscheme. This amounts to understanding the $t$-adic topology on this tensor product (e.g., is it separated?). Not sure if this helps. (Similar idea applies to any noetherian adic ring.)

Comment: @BCnrd: Thanks a lot for your comment. I am not familiar with fpqc descent. Do you think you could point me to a good place to start with this? Also, is there an elementary proof for my question above?

Comment: Dear Qph: Chapter 6 of "Neron Models" is a good place from which to learn descent theory. The natural map from $A_a[[t]] \otimes_{A[[t]]} A_{a'}[[t]]$ to $A_{aa'}[[t]]$ induces an isomorphism modulo $t^n$ for each $n \ge 1$, so the $t$-adic separatedness is equivalent to this natural map being injective. But such injectivity is unclear to me. 

Comment: On reflection, it seems to me likely that I overreached in my claim in the answer linked to by Gjergji Zaimi.  If $A$ is local, so that each
$A[t]/t^n$ is also local, then everything is okay, because maps from Spec $A[t]/t^n$ then necessarily factor through an affine open in the target.  In the more general setting, one has to contemplate BCnrd's comments ... .

Comment: Dear BCnrd: thanks a lot. I will look into this and contemplate about the problem.

Comment: Dear Emerton: thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: An addition to my comment: I should have noted that the "local" case was already pointed out by Martin Brandenburg above.