# When is a holomorphic submersion with isomorphic fibers locally trivial?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

A justly celebrated theorem by Ehresmann states that a proper smooth submersion $\pi: X\to S$ between smooth manifolds is  locally trivial in the sense that every point $s\in S$ downstairs has a neighbourhood $ U$ such that $\pi ^{-1} (U) $ is $S$-diffeomorphic (=fiber preserving diffeomorphism) to $U\times F$ for some manifold $F$, called the typical fiber. Of course the holomorphic analogon is completely false: deformation theory might be described as the study of this failure!

To give a concrete example, consider the family $X \subset S\times \mathbb P^2 (\mathbb C) $  of elliptic curves $y^2z=x(x-z)(x-\lambda z)$  with $\lambda \in S=\mathbb C \setminus \{0,1\} $ and the corresponding proper holomorphic submersion $\pi: X \to S: (\lambda , [x:y:z]) \mapsto \lambda $. This $\pi$  is  certainly not locally trivial downstairs because its fibers are not mutually isomorphic.

However, in the proper case, non-isomorphy of fibers is the only obstruction to being locally trivial. Indeed, Fischer and Grauert  proved that a proper holomorphic submersion having all its fibers isomorphic is locally trivial downstairs. I wonder what can be salvaged of their theorem in the non-proper case:

**Question:** Is there a class $\mathcal C$ of non-compact complex manifolds such that the following holds. If a holomorphic submersion $\pi: X\to S$ between complex manifolds has all its  fibers $\pi^{-1}(s)\;(s\in S)$  isomorphic to the same  $F \in \mathcal C$, then $\pi$ is locally trivial downstairs with typical fiber $F$.

**Bibliography** Fischer and Grauert unfortunately published their result in a rather confidential journal: W. Fischer, H. Grauert, Lokal-triviale Familien kompakter komplexer Mannigfaltigkeiten,
Nachr. Akad. Wiss. G¨ottingen Math.-Phys. Kl. II (1965), 89–94.

(Please note that the Fischer here is Grauert's doctoral student *Wolfgang* Fischer, not the complex geometer Gerd Fischer. )

Comment: I am confused about the Grauert-Fischer theorem, and I don't have a reference at hand (not to mention my german is not in very good shape). Certainly there exist proper maps $\pi \colon X \to S$, with both $X$ and $S$ compact, which are isotrivial on an open subset $U \subset S$, but not locally trivial. It seems to me that the restriction $\pi^{-1}(U) \to U$ is still proper, but does not satisfy the conclusion of the G-F theorem. :-?

Comment: I don't know the answer; but are there any know examples where the fibers are all isomorphic, but the family is not locally trivial?

Comment: Dear Andrea,  you write that there  "certainly" exist   counterexamples to Fischer-Grauert's theorem  (I suppose that by isotrivial you mean isomorphic fibers ?). What makes you think so ? You can find that theorem stated in English in Barth, Peters and Van de Ven's classic  book  *Compact Complex Surfaces* in Chapter I,Theorem 10.1 on page 29. In a way, I'm happy about your doubts: it shows how unbelievable Fischer-Grauert's theorem is!

Comment: Dear Angelo: no, there are no such examples because they are excluded by Fischer-Grauert's theorem! It seems this theorem doesn't have the celebrity it deserves, maybe because of the already mentioned relative obscurity of the journal where it was published. And also because of the language barrier: if articles are to be read, they must be written in Modern Latin, i.e. English!

Comment: So you are claiming that every isotrivial family of compact complex manifolds is actually locally trivial? I have to admit I do not have a proof of non-local-triviality for any isotrivial family (over $\mathbb{C}$) I can think of (and foor good reasons, apparently!) but then I wonder why the terminology... I wish I was always just told "here is a fiber bundle with fiber $F$".

Comment: Dear George, I thought that the result of Fischer and Grauert was for the proper case. My question was if there are known examples in the non-compact case.

Comment: Dear Andrea, yes I'm claiming that Fischer and Grauert proved that. I have no opinion on the terminology because I am not used to the adjective "isotrivial" in an analytic context ( although I know Serre introduced the notion  "espaces fibrés localement isotriviaux"  for algebraic varieties in the 1958 Séminaire Chevalley)

Comment: Dear Angelo: you are absolutely right, the Fischer-Grauert  theorem only tackles proper maps, as is stated in my question. As for an example where the analogon becomes false in the non proper case, here is a candidate. Take the open  ball $|z_1|^2+ |z_2|^2 \lt 1$ in $\mathbb C^2$and project it onto the unit disk in the $z_1$-plane.This is a submersion with all fibers isomorphic to a disk but I don't think it is  locally trivial, because of Poincaré's theorem that a bidisk is not isomorphic to a 2-dimensional ball. This is not a rigorous proof but I think one might transform it into one.

Comment: Dear Andrea, I don't know if the existence of a proper algebraically non-locally-trivial family with fixed fibers would contradict the FG theorem. After all, working complex analytically can give more "degrees of freedom" for trivialization. [Not directly related, but: incidentally it happens that all holomorphic line bundles over a punctured elliptic curve are holomorphically trivial, but the algebraic Pic of that variety is nontrivial...]. 

Comment: In other words, maybe it could happen that any such family is *analytically* locally trivial but it doesn't necessarily admit an *algebraic* trivialization.

Comment: Uhm... I understand the point. It would be very interesting to see a proper family which is analitically, but not algebraically, locally trivial.

Comment: @Andrea: take a look at the addendum to my answer below. The point is that if a family does not have a section, then it cannot be locally trivial. This way you get tons of examples.

Comment: @Andrea: take a non-Zariski-locally-trivial (locally isotrivial) projective fibration; then, by FG, it's locally (in the eucliden topology) analytically trivial. Or did you mean an explicit example?

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, do you know of any modern reference to the theorem by Fischer-Grauert (and perhaps of [this generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685867/fibrations-with-isomorphic-fibers-but-not-zariski-locally-trivial#comment2237438_1096176))?

Comment: Dear @Arrow: no, unfortunately I don't know such a modern reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a variant of Jason's example with a proof that it is not even topologically locally trivial. Let $T$ be a (complex) manifold that admits a morphism $\phi$ onto $\mathbb P^1=\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ (or $S^2$ if you prefer) and there exists a point $a\in T$ with $b=\phi(a)\in \mathbb P^1$ such that $\{a\}=\phi^{-1}(b)$. This is satisfied for example if $\phi={\rm id}_{\mathbb P^1}$. Let $\Gamma\subset T\times \mathbb P^1$ be the graph of $\phi$ and let  and $c\in \mathbb P^1, c\neq b$.

Now let $X=T\times \mathbb P^1\setminus \bigg( \Gamma\cup \big(T\times \{b\}\big)\cup \{(a,c)\}\bigg)$ with the natural projection $\pi:X\to T$. Then every fiber of $\pi$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1\setminus \{0,\infty\}\simeq \mathbb C^*\sim S^2\setminus \{P,Q\}$ (for two points $P,Q\in S^2$).

**Claim** $\pi$ is not topologically locally trivial near $a\in T$.

**Proof** Suppose $a$ has a neighbourhood $U\subseteq T$ such that $Y:=\pi^{-1}U\simeq U\times S^2\setminus \{P,Q\}$. Then there exists a projection $p:Y\to S^2\setminus \{P,Q\}$. Consider a circle in $S^2\setminus \{P,Q\}$ that's non-trivial in $H_1(S^2\setminus \{P,Q\}, \mathbb Z)$. Since $p$ is an isomorphism between $\pi^{-1}(a)$ and $S^2\setminus \{P,Q\}$, the same circle lives in $\pi^{-1}(a)$ as well. Then the homology class of the circle can be represented by a "small" circle around the point $(a,c)$ (this point is not in $X$!). Next take a "small" ball inside $T\times \mathbb P^1$ with center at $(a,c)$ that contains the previous "small" circle. By the construction of $X$, the intersection of this ball with $X$ is the entire ball except its center $(a,c)$. Therefore the homology class of that "small" circle in $X$ is trivial. However, this is a contradiction, because it was chosen in a way that its image via $p_*$ would be a nontrivial homology class. $\qquad {\rm Q.E.D.}$

**Remark** I suppose a similar proof works to show that Jason's example is also not locally trivial.

Comment: This is an interestingly unexpected (by me) technique, Sándor.

Comment: It's *ad hoc*. I tried to grasp the fact that the projection maps the complement of two lines and a single point to the complement of two points. If the map were algebraic one could argue many ways that this can't happen, but you seem to be hung up on holomorphic things. (wink-wink) :)

Comment:  To return the compliment, you seem to know a suspicious lot of holomorphic notions -like hyperbolic manifolds mentioned in your comment above- for a tough-boiled algebraic geometer :)

Comment: Georges, you are too kind to call this "returning the compliment". It's more like a gracious way to respond to a silly joke. On the other hand, I believe that a true tough-boiled algebraic geometer ought to know a little complex geometry and a little topology if for nothing else but motivation.

Answer (score 5):

If you drop the properness hypothesis, there are easy counterexamples.  For instance, begin with A^1 with coordinate t, and with A^2 with coordinates x and y.  Consider the projection p_1: A^1 x A^2 --> A^1, (t,(x,y)) --> t.  Now remove the closed subset C = Z(x(x-t),y) as well as the disjoint closed set which is the singleton {(0,(0,1))}.  Let X be the open complement.  Then p_1:X --> A^1 is flat, all geometric fibers are isomorphic -- each being the complement of two points in A^2, yet the morphism is not locally trivial.

Regarding Sandor's suggestion, something like this is written up in my joint paper with Johan de Jong on "almost properness" of GIT stacks.

Comment: 
 Dear Jason, thank you for your interesting answer. I'd like to insist that we are in a purely holomorphic setting, so I interpret $\mathbb A^1$    and $\mathbb A^2$  as $\mathbb C^1$     and $\mathbb C^2$     respectively and geometric fibers as fibers, all isomorphic to   $\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{{0,1 \}}$ . Your example is then very convincing but I confess that I cannot write down a proof that it is not locally trivial.

Comment: Consider the following variation on your construction. Start with $\mathbb C^2$    with coordinates $x,y$   ; delete both the  $x$-axis and the diagonal $x=y$  and also the point $(0,1)$  . Call $X$   the remaining open subset $X \subset  \mathbb C^2$   and project it down to the  $x$-axis. Do you think the submersion $ X \to \mathbb C$  thus obtained is locally trivial holomorphically? 

Comment: Georges, I don't think that this example will be locally trivial. I included a proof below that shows that if you do the same with adding the points at infinity on the fibers then it is not locally trivial. I think that a similar but more laborious proof would show that this example is also not locally trivial. 

Comment: Thanks again for your interest, Sándor. I also thought that my modification of Jason's example wasn't locally trivial but couldn't (and still can't) prove it. I have the feeling that Hartogs's theorem might be used in this context initiated by Jason. Anyway I am happy that your subtle argument below confirms that it is not trivial to show that all these submersions are not locally trivial!

Comment: Georges, I think you are right. By Hartog's theorem you can extend the projection map into the single point and then argue that the rest can't map to where it is supposed to.

Comment: ...what I meant was to extend the projection on the total space and then restrict to the fiber and get that $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ would have to map onto $\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$ which cannot happen as the latter is hyperbolic.

Comment:  Great, Sándor, I had this feeling that the concept "hyperbolic" might be relevant, but I was too ignorant to know whether this made sense. 

Comment: Georges, actually I think that the real reason is topological: you can't map a sphere minus $g$ points to a sphere minus $g+1$ points, especially that in this case it would have to be one-to-one outside one point. It was just easier above to say that a sphere minus two points is hyperbolic. However, I think to prove that it is, one might actually argue topologically. In other words, the same construction should work with cutting out more lines from C2 and making up with cutting isolated points out of the fibers where those lines intersect. For that the hyperbolicity argument would not work

Answer (score 3):

Taking your question to the realm of schemes I think that assuming something like that ${\rm Aut} F$ has a natural scheme structure gives you something that could be considered the algebraic equivalent of this statement.

Here is the argument. You can decide what needs to be assumed in addition to the above to get your goal.

Let $\pi:X\to S$ be a smooth morphism and $F$ a (smooth) variety such that $F\simeq X_s$ for all $s\in S$. Consider the relative ${\rm Isom}$ scheme
$$
{\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)\to S.
$$
This is a problem point as it might not exist. Or rather, the ${\mathscr Isom}$ functor is not necessarily representable. See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55042/automorphism-group-of-a-scheme/55050#55050) for a sketch of why this functor is representable for projective families and Torsten Ekedahl's answer to the same question for an easy example when it is not.

Anyway, if $I:={\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)$ exists, then consider the base change of your family to $I$,
$$
X_I=X\times_S I\to I,
$$
and consider the relative ${\rm Isom}$ scheme for the new family:
$$
{\rm Isom}_I(X_I,F\times I) \to I.
$$
Since the fibers of $X$ are isomorphic to $F$, the fibers of this scheme are isomorphic to ${\rm Aut} F$.

From the definition of the ${\mathscr Isom}$ *functor* it is clear that
$$
{\rm Isom}_I(X_I,F\times I)\simeq {\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)\times_SI = I\times_S I,
$$
so it admits a natural section over $I$. In other words, $X_I\simeq F\times I$.

So this proof seems to show that if ${\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)$ exists, then there is a base-change that trivializes $\pi:X\to S$. As a next step I would try to take multisections of ${\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)\to S$ to get a finite cover. You would probably want for each $s\in S$ a multisection that is unramified over $s$ to get an étale local trivialization. If you are happy with a local trivialization in the Euclidean topology (assuming you're working over $\mathbb C$) then this should do it. For the issue of local trivialization in the Zariski topology, see below.

Finally, this proof definitely shows that if $F$ is projective with a finite automorphism group, then $\pi:X\to S$ is étale locally trivial: the projectivity of $F$ implies the existence of ${\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)$ and the finiteness of ${\rm Aut} F$ implies that ${\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)\to S$ is a finite étale morphism.

To see the last statement, recall that the $I:={\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)$ functor/scheme is defined as an open subfunctor/subscheme of ${\rm Hilb}_S(X\times_S(F\times S))\simeq {\rm Hilb}_S(X\times F)=:H$. From the latter description it is clear that $H$ is flat over $S$. As $I$ is open in $H$, its closure in $H$, say $\overline I\subseteq H$ consist of a union of irreducible components of $H$ and hence it is also flat over $S$. Furthermore, $H$ is projective over $S$ and this implies that then $\overline I$ is finite and flat over $S$. Then it follows that the length of the fibers of $\overline I$ is constant. But the same is true for $I$ because its fibers over $S$ are isomorphic to the same automorphism group. Finally, as $\overline I$ is finite over $S$, $\overline I\setminus I$ cannot be dominant onto $S$, which implies that the general fiber of $\overline I$ and $I$ coincide. So the constant length of the fibers of both $\overline I$ and $I$ are the same and hence they are the same. In other words, $\overline I=I$ and hence $I$ is flat over $S$. As it has isomorphic fibers, it has to be unramified and hence étale.

**Addendum**

Regarding the discussion of families that are analytically but not algebraically locally trivial, an important difference is whether they have a section or not.

Assume that $\dim S=1$. Then if $\pi:X\to S$ is a smooth projective family without a section, then it cannot be algebraically locally trivial, since the closure of a section of the trivial part over a Zariski open set would give a section of the family. So, this way it is easy to find tons of examples.

On the other hand, a (quasi-)projective family over a curve will always have multisections, so it will have a section after a base change. So, for algebraically locally trivializing an isotrivial family the best hope is to do it after a finite base change. The above proof shows that if the appropriate $\mathscr Isom$ functor is representable by a quasi-projective scheme then this is doable. In particular, if $\pi:X\to S$ is projective, it can be trivialized with a finite base change (take a multisection of ${\rm Isom}_S(X,F\times S)\to S$).

Comment: Dear Sándor, although my question in principle concerns the holomorphic category, I thank you for your interest in it and for your remarks on their algebraic equivalent and the role of (multi)sections there. 

Comment: @SándorKovács thank you for the enlightening answer. May I ask: I don't see how to make the argument go though unless you knew the Isom scheme was flat over $S$. Then you could use descent to show it is finite etale. How does this work?

Comment: @BenC Good point, I should have explained that. I added an argument for that.