# Really rigid varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Are there (complex, projective) varieties $X_0$ with the following property?

> Every (flat, say) family $\mathfrak X\to T$ over a reasonable and reasonably big class of bases with a fiber over a closed point equal to $X_0$ is a trivial family, in the sense that $\mathfrak X$ is $T\times X_0$.

If one asks this with $T$ restricted to local Artinian rings, say, one gets the class of (infinitesimally) rigid varieties, but I wonder if there are "globally rigid" examples.

**Later:** As Francesco and unknowngoogle observe, it is quite unreasonable to ask for such strong rigidity... :)

Comment: Maybe the requirement $\mathfrak{X}\cong T\times X_0$ is too strong? I think when $X_0$ has a nontrivial automorphism one can often construct a nontrivial family (i.e. not $\cong$ to the product family) in which every fiber (over closed points) is $\cong$ to $X_0$.

Comment: @unknowngoogle: not any nontrivial automorphism will do. You need one which is "not homotopically trivial" in some sense. Your observation shows that $Aut(X_0)$ must be rationally connected. Given any automorphism $\phi$, you can form a family over the nodal cubic obtained by taking the trivial family over $\mathbb P^1$ and gluing two fibers together using $\phi$. A trivialization of this family produces a rational curve in $Aut(X)$ connecting $\phi$ to the identity.

Answer (score 12):

If $X_0$ is projectively embedded, we can use a Gr\"obner basis for its defining ideal to make a Rees family over ${\mathbb A}^1$ most of whose fibers are $X_0$, but whose central fiber is a monomial scheme. So $X_0$ must already be a monomial scheme. Since you said it's a variety, it must be a projective space. If you then allow me to reembed (by a Veronese), I could break that projective space, too, unless it's a point. So my answer: $X_0$ must be a point.

Answer (score 6):

If $X_0$ is a smooth *projective* variety over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $H^1(X_0, T_{X_0})=0$, then any deformation over a disk $D_{\epsilon}:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| < \epsilon \}$ is trivial for $\epsilon$ small enough.

Notice that, for a general scheme,  $H^1(X_0, T_{X_0})=0$ only ensures that there are no infinitesimal deformations (i.e. deformations over Artin rings); however, since $X_0$ is projective one shows that nearby fibers in *any* flat family of projective schemes are isomorphic to $X_0$ [see Hartshorne, Deformation theory, p. 39].

For instance, the complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ is globally rigid.

Another class of example is given by [Fake Projective Planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane): since they are $2$-dimensional ball quotients, they are globally rigid by Mostow Rigidity Theorem. In fact, their moduli space consists of $100$ distinct isolated points.

Let me also mention *Beauville surfaces*: they are surfaces $S$ of general type with $p_g=q=0$, $K_S^2=8$ (i.e. they are *fake quadrics*) obtained as $$S=(C_1 \times C_2)/G,$$
where $G$ is a finite group acting faitfully on the smooth curves $C_i$ and freely on their product, in such a way that $C_i/G \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ and  the two maps $ C_i \longrightarrow C_i/G$ are both branched at *three* points.

Since three points on the projective line have no moduli, by [general results of Catanese](http://muse.jhu.edu/login?uri=/journals/american_journal_of_mathematics/v122/122.1catanese.pdf) it follows that such surfaces are globally rigid, and in fact their moduli space is given again by a finite collection of reduced points.

Finally, notice that the $T=D_{\epsilon}$ is probably one of the most raisonable choices for checking global rigidity. In fact, if one choose as $T$ a compact complex curve, then even $X_0=\mathbb{P}^n$ fails to work: it is well known that there exist projective bundles over compact curves that are not trivial, think of Hirzebruch surfaces.

However, by using [Hartshorne, Deformation Theory, ex. 24.7 p. 163] one still have the following result:

Let $X_0$ be a projective scheme such that  $H^1(X_0, T_{X_0})=0$ and let $\mathfrak{X} \to T$ be a flat family of projective schemes over any nonsingular curve such that the central fibre is isomorphic to $X_0$. Then there exist a dominant base change $T' \longrightarrow T$ such that the family $\mathfrak{X}'=\mathfrak{X} \times_T T'$ is trivial over $T'$.

Comment: I agree that it is probably unreasonable to ask for *really global* rigidity over more global things than your $D_\varepsilon$ :) As you say, even the very rigid $\mathbb P^n$ fails to work. Are your examples (very nice ones, by the way: I was not aware of the existence of neither family, thanks!) *really global* or only over small balls? 

Comment: I do not know. One of the problems is that it is difficult to give conditions ensuring the triviality of a flat family $\mathfrak{X} \to T$ of proj. varieties over a projective variety $T$. One of the few results I'm aware of is contained in the paper by L. Migliorini "A smooth family of minimal surfaces of general type over a curve of genus at most one is trivial", J. Alg. Geom. 4 (1995). But, of course, this answers your question only for a very small class of projective bases $T$... 

Comment: For instance, looking at Migliorini's result, one could ask the following question: Let $\mathfrak{X} \to T$ be a smooth family of Fake Projective Planes, with $T$ a projective curve of genus at least $2$. Then by Mostow Rigidity Theorem it follows that it is isotrivial (i.e. all the fibres are isomorphic). Is it also *trivial*? Notice that by the last result I mentioned in my answer, it becomes trivial after a base change $T' \to T$. 

Comment: @FP: in which cases is the property "étal-locally trivial" the same as "all the fibers are isomorphic"?

Comment: @FP: (other question) In the last paragraph, is the nonsingular base curve also supposed to be projective?

Comment: just a comment: if $T$ has a non-trivial invertible sheaf ${\cal L}\in{\rm Pic}(T)$ then the projectivization of ${\cal L}\oplus{\cal O}_T$ gives a non-trivial $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $T$. For $T=\mathbb{P}^1$ we get the Hirzebruch surfaces Francesco already mentioned -- but it also produces non-trivial families of $\mathbb{P}^1$'s over affine (in particular: non-proper) bases. In particular, this highlights even further that $D_\epsilon$ is the only reasonable choice. 

Comment: @unknowngoogle A holomorphic submersion whose fibres ara *all* isomorphic is (analytically) locally trivial, i.e. trivial on an analytic open set of the base. This is the famous Grauert-Fischer theorem (continued)
 


Comment: (continued) It does not hold in this way in the algebraic category, since there are examples of algebraic isotrivial families without a section: if they were locally trivial, then the Zariski closure of a section in the local trivialization would give a section of the original family, contradiction (continued)

Comment: (continued) So, for algebraically locally trivializing an isotrivial family the best hope is to do it after a finite base change. The answer to your first question is that this is often possible (i.e. isotrivial ->etale loc. triv), see the second S. Kovacs' answer to this MO thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56737/when-is-a-holomorphic-submersion-with-isomorphic-fibers-locally-trivial

For your second question, in Hartshorne book on deformation the curve $T$ is assumed to be just *nonsingular*. No projectivity assumpions are made, but of course one can take it projective, if he likes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a notion of "deformation in the large", at least for smooth projective varieties.  A deformation in the large is any projective, $\textit{smooth}$ morphism over a connected base.  Your question does make sense for deformations in the large.  There are a number of varieties which are known to be rigid for deformations in the large, i.e., the morphism is a product étale locally over the base.  The first example is projective space (which follows, e.g., from Mori's solution of the Hartshorne conjecture).  I believe Siu first proved that hyperquadrics are rigid for deformations in the large.  And there has recently been phenomenal work of Jun-Muk Hwang and Ngaiming Mok establishing the same result for any irreducible Hermitian symmetric space, e.g., Grassmannians.

Comment: I think the OP is asking more than rigidity in the large in the usual sense (any deformation of $X_0$ over a connected basis is still $X_0$): he really wants that any flat family with central fiber $X_0$ is *trivial*. $\mathbb{P}^1$ dos not satisfy this condition, think of Hirzebruch surfaces. 