# Submersion and fiber bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

It is known by Ehresmann's result, that proper surjective submersions are fiber bundles. The properness of a map somehow relates to the compactness of the fibers or the level sets. So my question is as follows:

Is there an example of a differentiable map that is a submersion between differentiable manifolds $f: M \to N$ such that all level sets are diffeomorphic but $f$ is not a fiber bundle?

Comment: Yes, I have answered this several times on MO.  Remove from a projective line bundle two sections that intersect.  Over the divisor in the base where they intersect, remove a disjoint section.

Comment: @JasonStarr can you share the link?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136017/is-an-affine-fibration-over-an-affine-space-necessarily-trivial/136043#136043

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56737/when-is-a-holomorphic-submersion-with-isomorphic-fibers-locally-trivial/56761#56761

Comment: An interesting special case when a submersion $f$ is a fiber bundle: All fibers are diffeomorphic to $R^k$ for some fixed $k$. See: G. Meigniez, Submersions, fibrations and bundles. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 354 (2002), no. 9, 3771–3787.

Comment: @MoisheKohan.  I did not know that!  One of my examples is a submersion with fibers isomorphic to $2$-dimensional affine space, yet it is not an "affine morphism" .  Now I wonder whether it might be a holomorphic vector bundle?  The example in the other link is a submersion with fibers isomorphic to the one-point complement $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}$.  In a different MO answer, I prove that this example is not a fiber bundle: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286149/continuous-map-with-homeomorphic-fibers-whose-associated-hk-c-sheaf-is-not?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @JasonStarr: Yes, I noticed this. Maybe these are vector bundles in the holomorphic category. Unfortunately, Fischer and Grauert require properness to get from a smooth bundle to a holomorphic bundle.

Comment: In case you want to have more examples: There are surjective entire functions ${\mathbb C}\to {\mathbb C}$ without critical points, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147110/surjective-entire-functions-without-critical-points). It is easy to see that fibers of these maps are countably infinite.  But also, clearly, these are not covering maps, hence, not fiber bundles.