# Smooth morphism of smooth varieties with fibres isomorphic to an affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be *smooth* varieties over the field of complex numbers  $\bf C$
(smooth integral separated schemes of finite type over $\bf C$). Let
$$f\colon X\to Y$$
be a surjective morphism such that
for any closed point $y\in Y$, the schematic  fibre  $f^{-1}(y)\subset X$
is isomorphic to the affine space ${\Bbb A}_{\bf C}^{n(y)}$.
Moreover, assume that the morphism $f$ is *smooth* (which is equivalent to the assumption that $n(y)$
is the constant function $n(y)=n$, where $n=\dim X-\dim Y$).

Consider the real $C^\infty$-manifolds $X^\infty=X({\bf C})$ and $Y^\infty=Y({\bf C})$ and the induced $C^\infty$-map
$$f^\infty\colon X^\infty\to Y^\infty.$$
Since $f$ is smooth, the map $f^\infty$ is a submersion, that is, for any $x\in X^\infty$, the differential
$$d_x f\colon T_x(X)\to T_{f(x)}Y$$
is surjective. Moreover, each fibre of $f^\infty$ is diffeomorphic to ${\bf R}^{2n}$.
By Corollary 31 of [G. Meigniez, Submersions, fibrations and bundles,
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 354 (2002), no. 9, 3771-3787](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2002-354-09/S0002-9947-02-02972-0/S0002-9947-02-02972-0.pdf),
the map $f^\infty$ is a *locally trivial fibre bundle of $C^\infty$-manifolds*, that is, for any $y\in Y^\infty$
there exists an open neighborhood ${\mathcal U}_y$ of $y$ in $Y^\infty$
such that $f^{-1}({\mathcal U}_y)\simeq {\bf R}^{2n}\times {\mathcal U}_y$,
where $\simeq$ denotes a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism compatible with the projections onto ${\mathcal U}_y$.

> **Question 1.** Does it follow that the morphism $f$
> is a locally trivial fibre bundle in the étale topology,
> that is, for any closed point $y\in Y$
> there exists an étale open neighborhood $ U_y\to Y$ of $y$ such that
> $$X\times_Y U_y\simeq {\Bbb A}_{\bf C}^n\times_{\bf C} U_y\,,$$
> where $\simeq$ denotes an isomorphism of $\bf C$-varieties
> compatible with the projections onto $U_y$ ?

> **Question 2.** Is $f$ a locally trivial fibre bundle in the flat topology?

Consider the complex analytic manifolds  $X^{\rm an}=X({\bf C})$, $Y^{\rm an}=Y({\bf C})$
and the induced complex analytic morphism
$$f^{\rm an}\colon X^{\rm an}\to Y^{\rm an}.$$

> **Question 3.**  Is $f^{\rm an}\colon X^{\rm an}\to Y^{\rm an}$
> a locally trivial fibre bundle of complex analytic manifolds,
> that is, for any $y\in Y^{\rm an}$
> there exists an open neighborhood ${\mathcal U}_y$ of $y$ in $Y^{\rm an}$
> such that $(f^{\rm an})^{-1}({\mathcal U}_y)\simeq {\bf C}^n\times {\mathcal U}_y$,
> where $\simeq$ denotes an analytic isomorphism compatible with the projections onto ${\mathcal U}_y$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Question 1, it seems to be an open problem, known as a variant of Dolgachev–Weisfeiler Conjecture. The article [$\mathbb{A}^2$-fibrations between affine spaces are $\mathbb{A}^2$-trivial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04440.pdf) (A. Dubouloz) shows that an $\mathbb{A}^2$-fibration $f\colon X\to S$ is étale-locally trivial if and only if $\Omega^1_{X/S}$ is a pullback of a locally-free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on $S$. Similar questions are also mentioned in [Vénéreau polynomials and related fiber bundles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404904000325) (S. Kaliman, M. Zaidenberg), page 276. Perhaps some experts can answer this question in greater detail.

Comment: I am probably mistaken, but the paper by Dubouloz you mention seems to be interested in local trivilaity in the Zarisi topology, not in the étale topology.

Comment: @Libli I'm not an expert, but looking at the theorem in the introduction and Definitions 1 and 2, it seems that the result treats etale-local triviality, no? In any case, Zariski local triviality is even stronger, so gives a better answer to Q1?

Comment: @PiotrAtchinger I must have a problem with my English today but I read the following : "Summing  up, if an $\mathbb{A}^n$-fibration $\pi :V \longrightarrow X$ over an affine scheme $X$ is a **Zariski locally** trivial $\mathbb{A}^n$-bundle, then its relative cotangent sheaf is induced from $X$. Our main result, which can be summarized as follows, implies in particular that the converse holds for $\mathbb{A}^2$-fibrations over smooth affine schemes".

Comment: Furthermore, if I am not mistake, it is known that a smooth morphism is always locally trivial in the étale topology, isn't it EGA IV, 17.16.3 (ii)?

Comment: Locally trivial on the source, but not on the target!

Comment: @Libli The main result in the paper of Dubouloz (the theorem right below the passage you quoted) says that if $\Omega^1_{V/X}$ is induced from $X$, then $V$ is affine-linear bundle i.e. it is an étale-locally trivial $\mathbb{A}^2$-bundle on $X$, according to Definition 2.

Comment: @P.P : I don't claim that the result isn't true, I am just saying they prove much more. An affine-linear bundle is not just a locally trivial (in the étale topology) morphism with fibers being $\mathbb{A}^n$. As you can read just after definition 2 in the same paper : " every affine-linear bundle is actually locally trivial in the Zariski topology".

Comment: Good find! The first thing the paper says is that the paper considers affine morphisms. Is it even clear that a morphism $f$ as in the question is affine?

Comment: @Johan: A smooth map $f$ with fibers that are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$ need not be affine. Jason Starr gives an example $f\colon U\to B$ with $U$ quasi-affine, $B=\mathbb{A}^2$ and $n=2$ in https://mathoverflow.net/a/136043/40.

Comment: @DavidRydh Thanks!