# English reference for Fischer-Grauert theorem and its generalization by Schuster

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, several-complex-variables

From [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685867/fibrations-with-isomorphic-fibers-but-not-zariski-locally-trivial) and its answer, and from [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56737/when-is-a-holomorphic-submersion-with-isomorphic-fibers-locally-trivial) I have learned of the following remarkable theorem of Wolfgang Fischer and Hans Grauert.

**Theorem.** A proper holomorphic submersion with biholomorphic fibers is locally trivial.

[This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685867/fibrations-with-isomorphic-fibers-but-not-zariski-locally-trivial#comment2237438_1096176) on the former question states the theorem "has been generalized to the singular case by "Schuster, H.: Zur Theorie der Deformationen kompakter komplexer Räume. Inventiones math. 9, 284-294 (1970)." Moreover it says the methods of proof are completely new.

Where can I find a modern English reference for these results? What is the intuitive idea behind them?

Comment: Have you looked at the German article? I know that German is harder than French for many of us, but luckily complex geometry is not fundamentally different now, so the argument should not need any updating.

Comment: The first paragraph comes out of Google translate as: "The goal of the present work is to derive the following generalization of a theorem of Grauert and Fischer: If $p : X \to S$ is a real plate holomorphic mapping and all fibers of p are pairwise isomorphic, then p is trivial in any point of S if S is reduced." So I think you might not really need a translation.

Comment: "Real plate" should be "proper flat".